# Interpretation of two phrases separated by ‘or’, followed by another phrase starting with ‘and’

Tags: meaning, attachment-ambiguity

A sentence in the Indian Penal Code drafted in 1860 reads like this:

> Whoever commits murder shall be punished with death, or imprisonment for life, and shall also be liable to fine.

Someone interprets the sentence to mean that the question of liability to fine arises only in the case of imprisonment for life. His reasoning is based on the ground that the phrase ‘shall be liable to fine’ immediately follows the phrase ‘imprisonment for life’.

Another ground, an extraneous but logical one, is that it is meaningless to couple a fine with a death sentence because the person is not going to be deterred by threat of imprisonment in default of payment of fine.
But my understanding is that liability to fine will apply to both death and imprisonment for life.

What will be the correct grammatical interpretation of this sentence, leaving aside the futility of a fine imposed on a person facing capital punishment?

Comment: 'Whoever commits murder shall [A] be punished with (i) death, or (ii) imprisonment for life, and shall [B] also be liable to fine.' // I'd say the first comma is better dropped. //// Unless the estates of condemned persons are totally sequestered, the fine can be taken from that, leaving the residue.

Comment: The use of "or" and "and" is a topic more suitable for ELL

Answer (score 2):

In series, conjuncts should generally be parallel. The conjunct after "and" ("shall also be liable to fine") is clearly a complete predicate. Therefore, the first should also be a complete predicate. In that case, the only reasonable option is "shall be punished with death, or imprisonment for life". We can see that the issue of the fine is **not** connected only to the life sentence but is instead connected to **both** possible punishments.

By the way, the first conjunct itself contains a series, the second conjunct of which ("imprisonment for life") is surrounded by paired punctuation (along with the preceding conjunction). That is quite common, although the paired punctuation is extraneous in this case.

Note that my analysis takes a pretty traditional approach; other interpretations are certainly possible.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought too: one subject, two predicates

Comment: Agreed. Furthermore, the apparent futility of fining of a dead person does not cloud the analysis, because the fine may be exacted from the deceased’s estate (should they have any).